# JQuery $ajax only get items with a date before today

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following jQuery code:

```
var fetchResults = function () {
    return JSON.parse($.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Search/GetResults',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json'
        }).responseText);
    };
```

/Search/GetResults returns the JSON-format string of data.    /Search/GetResults accepts no criteria.

The data returned looks somewhat like this:

```
[{"title":"Sample 1 Title","Sample 1 Description":"","headline":"Sample 1 Headline","body":"","date":"2016-01-17 5:30:00"},{"title":"Sample 2 Title","Sample 2 Description":"","headline":"Sample 2 Headline","body":"","date":"2016-01-22 7:45:17},{"title":"Sample 3 Title","Sample 3 Description":"","headline":"Sample 3 Headline","body":"","date":"2016-01-27 15:26:17"},{"title":"Sample 3 Title","Sample 3 Description":"","headline":"Sample 4 Headline","body":"","date":"2016-01-29 18:00:00"}]
```

Using the example data shown above, I want fetchResults to only contain items where the "date" is before or equal to 2016-01-27 15:26:17 (an example point in time).   Is there is a function of the $.ajax that would allow me to perform filtering?

If so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Probably this has got something to do with your query.

Comment: The answer seems to be in your script/action at /Search/GetResults. I need more information about it.

Comment: Either change your response from `/Search/GetResults/`, or use JS to clean up your data based on the 'date'.  Either way, this is too broad a question and sounds like you're just asking for someone to write your code for you.  I'd suggest trying to work it out first, then coming here with the specifics of any problems you have.

Comment: Your question really says "tell me about dataFIlter" from here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for WHERE you can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example data has a missing quote but fix that and you could simply add a dataFilter to your ajax:

```
var fetchResults = function() {
  return JSON.parse($.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Search/GetResults',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    dataFilter: function(mydata) {
      var pdata = JSON.parse(mydata);
      var startDate = new Date("2016-01-27 15:26:17");// hard coded :)
      var dateLess = pdata.filter(function(r) {
        //console.log("r",r.date);// each date
        var d = new Date(r.date);
        return d <= startDate
      });
      return dateLess;//filtered data
    }
  }).responseText);
};
```

This returns:

```
[{
  "title": "Sample 1 Title",
  "Sample 1 Description": "",
  "headline": "Sample 1 Headline",
  "body": "",
  "date": "2016-01-17 5:30:00"
}, {
  "title": "Sample 2 Title",
  "Sample 2 Description": "",
  "headline": "Sample 2 Headline",
  "body": "",
  "date": "2016-01-22 7:45:17"
}, {
  "title": "Sample 3 Title",
  "Sample 3 Description": "",
  "headline": "Sample 3 Headline",
  "body": "",
  "date": "2016-01-27 15:26:17"
}]
```

Here is the sample filter working outside the ajax: https://jsfiddle.net/2wbdpfos/

Comment: weird, edited post and got new answer...deleted other one

Comment: NOTE: you might or might not want to use stringify on the return i.e. `return JSON.stringify(dateLess);`

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.   The API page was severely lacking in documentation about how to implement the dataFilter but this was the perfect reusable/adaptable code explanation.   Would upvote multiple times if I could.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the service you're hitting, it's impossible to say how to get the results you are seeking. *However*, if your only goal is to get a subset of that array, you could simply do a loop like the following through the array of results.

```
// I'm using the name "results" for the variable where you store
//  the results of your Ajax call

// Loop through every element of results
for(var i = results.length; i--;) {
    // Determine if the date is in the past
    if(Date.parse(results[i].date) < new Date()) {
        // Remove the result
        results.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Please note that it is important that you loop through the array *backwards*, as the element at index "i" could fluctuate as you splice elements otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on looping the array backwards, I've had this issue before.